# Tiled map loading wrong in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, tiled

I figured this would be perfect avenue of learning for me, since I love games and you can easily see how changes in code interact with the game.

In this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJMDh9QGRgs&t=3966s I encountered a problem that I just can't seem to be able to figure out myself. No error messages. It just loads the map wrong.

[This is how it should about look like. Placement in mine is a bit different.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20xdg.png)

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A13pZ.png)

This is how the level_0_terrain.csv where it should load the positions looks like:

[level_0_terrain.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rKuL.png)

The tutorial uses multiple different files to build the game. Since I have no idea what went wrong here are all files:

**main**

```
import pygame, sys
from settings import * 
from level import level
from game_data import level_0

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
level = level(level_0,screen)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            
    screen.fill("black")
    level.run()
    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

**settings**

```
vertical_tile_number = 11
tile_size = 64

screen_height = vertical_tile_number * tile_size
screen_width = 1200
```

**level**

My main suspect where things go wrong. Haven't been able to figure out what is the issue.

```
import pygame
from support import import_csv_layout
from settings import tile_size
from tiles import Tile

class level:
    def __init__(self,level_data,surface):
        self.display_surface = surface
        
        terrain_layout = import_csv_layout(level_data["terrain"])
       # print(terrain_layout)
        self.terrain_sprites = self.create_tile_group(terrain_layout,"terrain")
    
    def create_tile_group(self,layout,type):
        sprite_group = pygame.sprite.Group() 
        
        for row_index, row in enumerate(layout):
            for col_index,val in enumerate (row):
                if val != "-1":
                    x = col_index * tile_size
                    y = col_index * tile_size
                    
                    if type == "terrain":
                        sprite = Tile(tile_size,x,y)
                        sprite_group.add(sprite)
                    
        return sprite_group
        
    def run(self):
        # Run this entire game / level
        self.terrain_sprites.draw(self.display_surface)
```

**support**

Here I could not load the file without direct path. Not sure if related but at least if I use print it seems to read level_0_terrain.csv correctly

```
from csv import reader

def import_csv_layout(path):
    terrain_map = []
    
   # with open(path) as map:
    with open(r"C:\Users\XXXX\Python games\Mariolike\levels\0\level_0_terrain.csv") as map:
    #with open(r"C:/Users/XXXX/Python games/Mariolike/levels/0/level_0_terrain.csv") as map:
        level = reader(map,delimiter = ",")
        for row in level:
#            print(row)
            terrain_map.append(list(row))
        return terrain_map
```

**tiles**

```
import pygame

class Tile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,size,x,y):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size,size))
        self.image.fill("grey")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x,y))
```

**Game_data**

```
level_0 = {
    "terrain":"..levels/0/level_0_terrain.csv",
    "coins":"..levels/0/level_0_coins.csv",
    "fg palms": "..levels/0/level_0_fg_palms.csv",
    "bg palms": "..levels/0/level_0_bg_palms.csv",
    "crates": "..levels/0/level_0_crates.csv",
    "enemies": "..levels/0/level_0_enemies.csv",
    "constraints": "..levels/0/level_0_constraints.csv",
    "player": "..levels/0/level_0_player.csv",
    "grass": "..levels/0/level_0_grass.csv"}
```

Comment: do you use `col_index` twice for x and y on purpose ? shouldn't that be `row_index` for y in class `Level` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are assigning an incorrect value for `y`. It should be `y = row_index * tile_size`.

```
if val != "-1":
    x = col_index * tile_size
    y = row_index * tile_size
```

Comment: That did it. Can't believe I did not see it myself. Thanks a lot.